# how do i make a custom color in basic javascript

Tags: javascript

In my intro coding class I'm having trouble warping my head around making custom colors, and the teacher couldn't explain it well enough, and CodeHS also doesn't explain well enough either.

```
*// You can also make your own color by giving a red, green,
// and blue component like
//*
var color = new Color(r, g, b);

*// Another way to set the color of an object is to use a
// string with the hexadecimal color value with setColor.
// For example, to set a rect object to be pink:
//*
rect.setColor("#FF66CC");
```

This is all CodeHS explains and doesn't give good examples.
Can someone mock up an example of some code a newbie can understand?

Comment: Read something about the RGB color model. That should explain it all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are confusing JavaScript and Java.

There is no such object like `Color` or `Rectangle` in JavaScript.

However, there are such objects and methods in `Java`:

[Graphics Reference](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Graphics/GraphingFill.htm)

[Color Reference](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/GraphicssetColorColorc.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're working in CodeHS, here's a good example of how to use it.

```
var -var name- = new Color(r, g, b);
```

the R, G, and B represent the Red, Blue, and Green values of the color. You can look up RGB values for custom colors on Google. You can then use the color on a shape or something other by this example-

```
-var name-.setColor(-var name of color-);
```

Hope this helps.